# How to monitor, that data is retrieved from INMEMORY?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I'm tuning INMEMORY COLUMN STORE in Oracle 12c DB. How to understand, that data collects from INMEMORY, not from general DB?

I can't get this information from Plan in SQL Developer.

Comment: Execution plan will show that. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a SQL statement is scanning data in the `IM column` examine the `execution plan`.

For example :

**`TABLE ACCESS INMEMORY FULL`**

The keyword, `INMEMORY` in the `Operation` proves that it is an `IM` table scan.

In `SQL Developer`, use the `EXPLAIN PLAN` tool or press `F10` to generate the execution plan.

Comment: You can also check out the AutoTrace results and the new in-memory stats, an example here [link](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/30-sql-developer-tips-in-30-days-day-16-comparing-in-memory-results-with-autotrace/)

Comment: @thatJeffSmith, that's of course another option. But more of a work for a trivial thing. OP said, he can't see it mentioned in the execution plan ;-)

Comment: That's why I left it as a comment and not an answer. More info is always better, yes? Also, the AutoTrace shows the plan, and the plan shows whether if in-memory comes into play or not.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B Hm, I've got it. Now another problem, so I'm loading table to inmemory w/ CRITICAL PRIORITY. But Data didn't collected from INMEMORY. In Operation it says: TABLE ACCESS (FULL)

Comment: That is out of scope of your original question. Please open a new question fo rit.

Comment: Already done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273969/how-to-collect-data-from-inmemory-partition